# C++ variable gotten from GETTEXT as a mysql_query variable

Tags: c++, mysql, winapi, unicode

I'm trying to do the following:

1. get username typed into the userField
2. make a SEARCH mysql_query with the username as a variable

I'm having a hard time getting past phase 2 since mysql_query takes a const char* as the query string, and I can only get username as char* or wchar_t*

I'm also compiling in unicode.

My code for now:

```
void mysql_connect(HWND hLoginWnd) {

MYSQL *con, mysql;
MYSQL_RES *res;
mysql_init(&mysql);

mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");

mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "", "treenitaulu", 3306, NULL, 0);

char name[512], pass[512];
int lenUser = SendMessage(userField, WM_GETTEXT, 512, (LPARAM)name);
int lenPass = SendMessage(passField, WM_GETTEXT, 512, (LPARAM)pass);

if(lenUser > 0 && lenPass > 0) {

    std::string query = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='" + std::string(name) + "'";

    mysql_query(&mysql, query.c_str());

}

}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the SQL charset to UTF-8, so use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert the retreived UI Unicode strings into UTF-8, then pass the converted data to the DB query.  UTF-8 encoded data can be stored using `char` buffers, and you can pass a `char*` (or `char[]`) where a `const char*` is expected.  For example:

```
std::string Utf8Encode(WCHAR *wStr, int wLen)
{
    int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wStr, wLen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8len > 0)
    {
        std::vector<char> utf8(utf8len);
        utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wStr, wLen, &utf8[0], utf8len, NULL, NULL);
        if (utf8len > 0)
            return std::string(&utf8[0], utf8len);
    }
    return std::string();
}

void mysql_connect(HWND hLoginWnd)
{
    MYSQL *con, mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    mysql_init(&mysql);

    mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");

    mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "", "treenitaulu", 3306, NULL, 0);

    WCHAR name[512];
    int lenUser = SendMessage(userField, WM_GETTEXTW, 512, (LPARAM)name);

    if (lenUser > 0)
    {
        std::string query = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='" + Utf8Encode(name, lenUser) + "'";
        mysql_query(&mysql, query.c_str());
        ...
    }
}
```

With that said, you really need to escape strings when building SQL statements dynamically.  It is safer as it is not prone to SQL Injection attacks:

```
std::string Utf8EncodeAndEscape(MYSQL *mysql, WCHAR *wStr, int wLen)
{
    int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wStr, wLen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8len > 0)
    {
        std::vector<char> utf8(utf8len);
        utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wStr, wLen, &utf8[0], utf8len, NULL, NULL);
        if (utf8len > 0)
        {
            std::vector<char> escaped(utf8len*2+1);
            unsigned long escapedLen = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql, &escaped[0], &utf8[0], utf8len);
            if (escapedLen > 0)
                return std::string(&escaped[0], escapedLen);
        }
    }

    return std::string();
}

void mysql_connect(HWND hLoginWnd)
{
    MYSQL *con, mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    mysql_init(&mysql);

    mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");

    mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "", "treenitaulu", 3306, NULL, 0);

    WCHAR name[512];
    int lenUser = SendMessage(userField, WM_GETTEXTW, 512, (LPARAM)name);

    if (lenUser > 0)
    {
        std::string query = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='" + Utf8EncodeAndEscape(&mysql, name, lenUser) + "'";
        mysql_query(&mysql, query.c_str());
        ...
    }
}
```

Parameterized queries would be just as safe, but are more efficient than dynamic SQL statements, especially if you need to execute the same statement multiple times:

```
std::wstring Utf8Decode(char *utf8Str, int utf8Len)
{
    int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8Str, utf8Len, NULL, 0);
    if (wLen > 0)
    {
        std::vector<wchar_t> wStr(wLen);
        wLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8Str, utf8Len, &wStr[0], wLen);
        if (wLen > 0)
            return std::wstring(&wStr[0], wLen);
    }
    return std::wstring();
}
```

```
MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(&mysql);
if (stmt)
{    
    std::string query = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name=?"
    if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, query.c_str(), query.length()) == 0)
    {
        if (mysql_stmt_param_count(stmt) == 1)
        {
            std::string utf8User = Utf8Encode(name, lenUser);
            unsigned long utf8len = utf8User.length();
            MYSQL_BIND param = {0};
            param.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
            param.buffer = utf8User.c_str();
            param.buffer_length = utf8len;
            param.length = &utf8len;
            param.is_unsigned = true;
            mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, &param);

            char result[512];
            unsigned long resultLen = 0;
            MYSQL_BIND result = {0};
            param.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
            param.buffer = &result[0];
            param.buffer_length = 512;
            param.length = &resultlen;
            param.is_unsigned = true;
            mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, &result);

            if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt) == 0)
            {
                mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt);
                mysql_stmt_free_result(stmt); 

                SendMessage(passField, WM_SETTEXTW, 0, (LPARAM) Utf8Decode(result, resultLen).c_str());
            }
        }
    }
}

mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
```

Comment: Holy bamboo. That hocus pocus did the trick! Unicode makes life so hard... Thanks man. Oh, and what are parameterized queries? Google isn't bringing any light. EDIT: found it. "prepared statement".